# Loaded Windows minidump file, now can't load binary?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, minidump

I loaded the minidump file into Visual Studio 2010, loaded all they symbols, both from my program folder and the Microsoft Symbol Server, then I chose "Debug Native Only" and the program ran up to where it crashed with the same error as displayed on the remote computer when the exe crashed.

Now an error "program.exe not found" and "program.exe was not found in the minidump. you need to load the binary in order to find the source for the current stack frame"

When I click on 'Browse and find program.exe', I select it but VS won't open it?

Comment: Best to focus on the "mini" in minidump.  It contains the minimum data required to restore a debug session.  It *excludes* the original code in the EXE and DLL files.  If you don't have an **exact** match with those files that the crashing computer used then the debugger is going to get sulky.  Exact match is byte-for-byte identical and the exact same timestamp on the file.  If you don't have a copy anymore then ask the customer to send them back to you.

Comment: @HansPassant, the customer has the exe file that created the minidump file, and I have the matching pdb file and source files. So, I'm not sure what to do next and why VS won't open the exe? Any thoughts how to proceed?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/81681f0f-42ac-469f-85bc-cb85b8771e60/cant-load-executable-to-go-with-crash-mini-dump?forum=vsdebug

Comment: no this cannot help. it just lists several more people having the issue, and no helpful answer. I'm just stuck with the same issue and will post an answer here if we can figure it out.

Answer (score 9):

This dialog "Browse and find ..." tells us two important bits of information:

- where it is looking by default (the full path)
- the name of the file it attempts to load (exe or dll)

At the same time, it is silent about two more facts:

- it is looking for a exename.pdb / dllname.pdb in the same directory
- it checks for an exact (size and timestamp) match in the binary and does not bother to tell, the "Open" button just idles.

As soon as you pick the file it asks for, put it in the direcory it looks at, and add the corresponding pdb file, it will definitely work. Only be 100% sure the dll/exe/pdb combination you offer to the debugger is the very same one that was running at the time the minidump was created.

Comment: I think this is clear. The question is where to get the vcruntime140.dll since this is a microsoft library, the microsoft symbol server should pass this automaticaly

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, and the solution I found is dumb, but would help someone who is stuck. This issue is still seen on latest VS 2019.

So, the trick is to use the "Browse and find the *.dll" link, open the folder where your binary is located. Copy the binary and in the same window, paste it to a different location on your computer. Now click "Open". It should load the binary and show you the callstack!

Got help from this thread - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/81681f0f-42ac-469f-85bc-cb85b8771e60/cant-load-executable-to-go-with-crash-mini-dump?forum=vsdebug